# Why do these characters have a giant stack of accent marks?

Tags: html, char

Have you ever noticed this character in webpage, ฏ๎ํ? Produced by 0x0EOF, 0x0E4E and 0x0E4D.

I could find some information here: http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/3599.

But, it should actually be three characters put together, why in webpage, it seems that it never ends?

(KUbuntu 12.04 Chrome Version 23)

[image]

Comment: "It never ends"? I don't understand. Are you asking why it is represented by three bytes?

Comment: @Quentin,ฏ๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎ํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํ,when you copy this character to a text file, it's huge. when you search it on google, google retures 414 =P

Comment: Define "huge". Does your editor display it in a large font size? Does your editor save it in a file with a large file size? What editor are you using? Have you tried a different editor? What character encoding settings do you have your editor configured to use?

Comment: @Quentin Now you see the effect?

Comment: Nope, still don't know what you mean by "never ends".

Comment: @gb18030, you have now changed the start of the question heading to contain a long string of diacritic marks. Are you seriously asking why it causes diacritic marks to be stacked?

Comment: @deceze I think the character ฏ๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎๎ํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํํ should look odd in my browser

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I dont know what's it, I saw it in my friends status, and when I copied it to Emacs, I descovered actually only three characters put together. I just dont understand why it appears different in Chrome

Comment: With a long string of diacritics, it is an artificial creation used for cheap fun, and the rendering varies by rendering software and font. I do not see anything programming-related here.

Comment: Seems to me that Thai character shouldn't appear in a Chinese language text so frequently anyway. There's gotta be more problems there...

Comment: this should be posted on superuser and is duplicated with: http://superuser.com/questions/389333/how-do-i-find-out-which-language-some-unicode-characters-belong-to

Comment: @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior ! Thanks! I know somewhere here must have answers. But I just dont know how to search for it! Case closed =P

Comment: ⚠️This question may need editing⚠️

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a massively accentuated char, you can do this with latin characters too, for example â̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂ is a a with many circumflexes in it.

This is how â̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂̂ is displayed in a hex editor:
[image]

So you can see there's a lot of `CC 82`, they are [COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=768&number=128), let's analyze:

1. `EF BB BF`: [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
2. `C3 A2`: [LATIN SMALL LETTER
   A WITH CIRCUMFLEX](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl): â
3. `CC 82`: [COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=768&number=128):
   ^ (mixed with the preview letter)

Now let's try our own, I did: `EF BB BF C3 AB CC 88 CC 88 CC 88`... and this is the result: ë̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈̈

[image]

1. `EF BB BF`: [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
2. `C3 AB`: [LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH DIAERESIS](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl): ë
3. `CC 88`: [COMBINING DIAERESIS](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=768&number=128): ¨

---

### Is this a rendering problem?

Actually, the binary sentence tell the system to do that "infinite chars", they are not actually infinite, they have a limit, but when people do this they do for fun and put lots of accents in the letter, making people believe it's infinity, for example, this a has 2 tildes only: ã̃ , this other has 3: ã̃̃, the next has a lot: ã̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃̃, this combines with acute: ã̃́̃́̃́̃́̃́̃́̃́̃́̃́̃́̃́̃́̃́

Comment: Yep, so is it just a rendering problem?

Comment: @gb18030 it is not a rendering problem. It is what is commonly known as "garbage in, garbage out".

Comment: @gb18030 I've edited to answer the comment

Comment: @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior Thanks. Garbage in, garbage out =)

Answer (score -1):

This is the way the character is displayed for me:

[image: ฏ๎ํ]

(OS X 10.8, Safari)

If it's not displayed the same way for you but the diacritics are spaced out in some weird fashion, it means your system cannot handle the display of this complex combined character correctly.

Comment: [This is how it looks for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/B167c.png) and presumably for the OP too.

Comment: @MartinSmith what's your browser? I used chrome. I just dont understand it

Comment: I tried in IE9, FF and Chrome all looked the same. In Win7

Comment: I'm no expert in Thai typography, but it just seems to be the base character ฏ combined with ๎ and ํ. These three should not repeat forever. Seems like the Thai handling on your systems is buggy... Oh, it's Windows. Case closed. ;-P j/k

Comment: @deceze While, I believe it's more kind of a bug in Chrome. 'cause no such problem in my IE.

Comment: @gb18030 Chrome on OS X displays it fine as well. It's either a Chrome-for-Windows bug or a weird interaction between Windows' and Chrome's font rendering.